# wxpython - how can I keep a line of text staying at the bottom right corner of a scrolledwindow?

Tags: python, wxpython

Thanks for any suggestion
Below is my code

```
def _OnPaint(self, evt):
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
    self.DoPrepareDC(dc)
    dc.Clear()
    nLeft, nTop = self.GetViewStart()
    print nLeft, nTop
    dc.DrawText('hello', nLeft + 100, nTop)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't draw the text. Just use a wx.StaticText widget. Put the ScrolledWindow into a sizer and then add the static text widget. Voila! You're done!

If you want to go the drawing route, then you will have to bind to the scrolling events and figure out where in the scrolled area you are. Then re-draw the text whenever the scrollwheel stops. This will be a LOT more work.

Comment: thx. Finally I used the StaticText way, looks somewhat ugly though.